# Question follow feature like Quora

Tags: feature-request

Like Quora, we need the ability to follow a good question that we really need to know the new answers that added in future.

Answer (score 2):

Just click the star:

[image]

And then you can see updates under favorites in your profile:

[image]

Comment: So that mean I will receive update when the new ans or comments added